# How to generate an identifier for all the groups that contains same set of data with SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table contains the bus line schedule like this:

```
    SELECT
            NULL AS CALENDARDATE
           ,NULL AS BUS_ID
           ,NULL AS STOP_ID
           ,NULL AS TIME
      FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1003', '8:39' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1003', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:20' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:40' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:50' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:22' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:40' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:50' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:20' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:40' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:50' FROM DUAL ;
```

The goal is to compress the data, we'll create a schedule_id instead of redundant data for each day.

Which means for the same day, for the same bus line, if all its routes pass exact the same stops and on exact the same time, then we should geneate the same schedule id for this day and bus combination every time.

I have tried to resolve this by two loops, the outer loops day by day, the inner loops for each bus line, however it takes too much time to finish as the data quantity is huge. (around 500 millions per year) .

I know I can use XML Path to achieve this in SQL Server, but that does not work in Oracle, I am sure there must be some other elegent solution in Oracle, but I am still new to Oracle so I am here seeking for help.

The environment is Oracle 11G.

Expected result:

```
    SELECT
            NULL AS SCHEDUL_ID
           ,NULL AS CalendarDate
           ,NULL AS BUS_ID
           ,NULL AS STOP_ID
           ,NULL AS TIME
        FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190101',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190102',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_02', '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_02', '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_02', '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_02', '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_02', '20190103',  100, 'STOP_1003', '8:39' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_03', '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_03', '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_03', '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_03', '20190104',  100, 'STOP_1003', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1000', '8:35' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:32' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_100_01', '20190105',  100, 'STOP_1001', '8:37' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:20' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:40' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190101',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:50' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_02', '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:22' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_02', '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_02', '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:40' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_02', '20190102',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:50' FROM DUAL UNION

    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:20' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:30' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:40' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'SCHEDULE_2019_101_01', '20190103',  101, 'STOP_1002', '8:50' FROM DUAL
```

Once I have the expected result, the rest is easy, I can split the data into two tables: 
First one contains the mapping of date and schedule_id, 2nd one contains the schedule_id, stop and times.

P.S. You can ignore the row with NULL value, it just serves for the readability for column names in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` and, say, `dense_rank()`.  First categorize using `listagg()`:

```
select calendardate, busid,
       listagg(stopid || '-' || time, ',') within group (order by time) as stops
from buslines
group by calendardate, busid;
```

Then assign a value:

```
select b.*,
       rank() over (order by busid, stops) as scheule_number
from (select calendardate, busid,
             listagg(stopid || '-' || time, ',') within group (order by time) as stops
      from buslines
      group by calendardate, busid
     ) b;
```

Note that this includes the `busid` in the ranking, so two buses that makes the same stops have different schedule numbers.

Comment: The query runs fine on test env, however on prod env it give error : SQL Error: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long, I think I have to create a user defined agg function.

Comment: @AdamYan . . . How long is the longest busline?  A stopid and time should be about 10 characters.  I would think that 100 stops would be a lot for a bus.  You may be able to filter the outliers.

Comment: I could reach to 50+ stops and 100+ times. so that is 5000 cominations * 5 *2 = around 50000 charaters per day per busline.

Comment: @AdamYan . . . With 50 stops, you might be able to encode the stops and times into less than 15 characters.  If so, then the strings may not exceed the built-in limit.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I got it working, because the origianl data is using overlapping date range, like date_from and date_to, so I used ListAGG funciont on  date_from || date_to' and this bypass the 01489 error.  I am also planning to use ORA_HASH for the LISTAGG result, so I will have stable identifier instead of non-stable rank() results.